# when i am sending email from my php code through a 3rd party mail server, where do i save my emails?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am using php code to send emails to gmail or yahoo ids. i am using a 3rd party mail server to send my emails. my php code works and i can receive the content in my gmail inbox. but where do i save my sent emails ?? who gives me an inbox for all my received / sent emails. suggest me a Name ?

```
function helloEmail()
{
    $from = new Email(null, "test@example.com");
    $subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library";
    $to = new Email(null, "test@example.com");
    $content = new Content("text/plain", "some text here");
    $mail = new Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);
    $to = new Email(null, "test2@example.com");
    $mail->personalization[0]->addTo($to);

    //echo json_encode($mail, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
    return $mail;
}
```

Comment: it's realted to your 3rd party mail server.

Comment: `sending` emails and `receiving` them are two distinct fields; you need different protocols for `sending` and `receiving` emails

Comment: The mailserver. The login credentials you are using to send to the mail server (smtp) can also be used to access the mailboxes (pop, imap). you will need to get the correct server addresses and ports from the mailserver provider. You can also write your own program but you will still need to interface with the mailservers on the other end.

Comment: PHPMailer just isn't involved with this. You can obtain a copy of a message by calling `getSentMIMEMessage()` and pass that to some IMAP code. Normally this would be done by your mail server - saving a copy in your 'sent' mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbox for your sent mails. You can send an e-mail using any e-mail address you choose, even if it belongs to someone else or doesn't exist.

For your received e-mail inbox, you'll have to make one yourself via any third party e-mail service such as Gmail or Hotmail, or via your web hosting platform using your own domain name if they provide e-mail services.

To save your sent e-mails you can opt to save them in a database.